# Trying to call a servlet when loading a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am building a simple Train booking system, now i am trying to call a servlet once i open a jsp to select data from the database then return back to the same servlet, but i keep getting errors.

this is my trip.jsp

```
<body>
     <% if ((request.getAttribute("trips") == null)) {
    %>

    <jsp:include page="/trips" flush="true" />
    <% } %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Trip Number</th>
            <th>Train Number</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Departure Time</th>
            <th>Arrival Time</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Reserved Seats</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    <%
        //ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        List trip = new ArrayList();
        Iterator viewTrip;
        if(request.getAttribute("trips")!=null && request.getAttribute("trips")!=""){
            List allTrips = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("trips");
            Iterator itr = allTrips.iterator();

            while(itr.hasNext()){
                trip = (ArrayList)itr.next();
                viewTrip = trip.iterator();
                %>
                <tr>
                    <%
                        while(viewTrip.hasNext()){
                            %>
                            <td>
                                <%=viewTrip.next()%>
                            </td>
                            <%
                        }
                    %>
                </tr>
                <%
            }
        }
    %>

    </table>
</body>
```

and this is my servlet. trips.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        Connection con = DB.getActiveConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;

        ArrayList trip = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = null;

        try {
            String query = "select * from trips";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
                data = new ArrayList();

                data.add(rs.getString(9)); // trip number
                data.add(rs.getInt(1)); // train number
                data.add(rs.getString(2)); // source 
                data.add(rs.getString(3)); // destination
                data.add(rs.getTime(4)); //departure time
                data.add(rs.getTime(5));// arrival time
                data.add(rs.getDate(6));// date
                data.add(rs.getInt(7));// reserved seats 
                data.add(rs.getDouble(8));//price


                trip.add(data);
            }
            request.setAttribute("trips", trip);
            con.close();
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/updateTrip.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.include(request, response);
            //out.close();
            //return;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and this is the error i get

```
    25-Dec-2016 15:47:01.822 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-4]         
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for     servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Train] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data] with root cause
 java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:200)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.updateTrip_jsp._jspService(updateTrip_jsp.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: While Gurwinder Singh's answer below is likely the reason, believe your application could benefit from an MVC design pattern. It helps if you learn doing things the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`try with resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which automatically closes the stream while exiting the try block.

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
....
}
```

`trip.jsp` passes request and response objects to the servlet `trips.java`, where you get the `PrintWriter` of the response (and for some reason, not using it anywhere) in a `try with resource`, which will close the underlying stream at the end of the try block. Now, when your include is finished and control comes back to the `trip.jsp` and try to write the jsp content, it'll **fail** as the stream is already closed.

Just change your code as:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
....
} catch (IOException e) {
....
}
```

or if you don't want to handle the exception here, just remove the try altogether.

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful.